# get selected row Id from jquery datatable version 1.9.4

Tags: jquery, datatables

Sorry this may be a duplicated question, but couldn't able to find the solution any where in the web as well as in StackOverflow

**Problem**

I need to get the selected row id from jquery data table

**My code what I have tried**

```
$.each($("#myDataTable").dataTable().fnGetNodes(), function (i, row) {
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                   console.log(id)
            });
```

The selected TR has the class row_selected selected

> class="even row_selected selected"

So I need to get the id of the selected row based on this selected class, please help in solving this issue

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$()`](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref) API method to perform a jQuery selector action on the table's `TR` elements.

For example:

```js
$("#myDataTable").dataTable().$("tr.selected").each(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: yeah am getting the id, and updating the row using fnupdate, but after updation it reloads to the 1st page, its not staying up in the same page itself do you have any idea on this issue plz

Comment: You may want to avoid redrawing the table with `fnUpdate` by  setting two last arguments to `false` and use plug-in [`fnStandingRedraw`](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnStandingRedraw).

Comment: plugin code must be pasted in separate js file or the same datatables.js, can u just say me that please

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav, plug-in code could be in the main JS file or loaded from separate JS file, it doesn't matter as long as it is available before you call the method.